# "I appreciate for your status update" vs "I appreciate the update"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> "I appreciate for your status update"

vs

> "I appreciate the update"

The latter may sound more normal but when grading someone's writing, what are the technicalities that I can use to explain why the first one is a little off?

Comment: “Appreciate” is a transitive verb- it requires a direct object. Using “for” doesn’t make sense here.

Comment: @Mixolydian's comment is the whole of the answer. The particular kinds of object or complement a verb takes are part of the dictionary entry for that verb, and have to be learnt. They cannot be worked out by logic, meaning, or analogy.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are OK (provided you delete the "for": appreciate for... is not OK).

So:

> "I appreciate your status update"

and

> "I appreciate the update"

are equally OK. The following is OK too:

> "I appreciate **the** status update".

The only difference between them is the amount of information contained, related to "update": the "your" and the "status".

One or another may prove better, depending on context.